# How can I trasform a (1,16) array in a (1,16,1) array with np.newaxis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to trasform this array (1, 16)

```
[[4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 0]]
```

in a (1,16,1) array.

I tried:

```
board = board[np.newaxis, :]
```

but it is not the expeted output.

How can i do that?

Comment: `board[:, np.newaxis]`

Comment: What is the unexpected output?

Comment: @MadPhysicist an array with the shape (1, 16, 1)

Answer (score 3):

You have to put the `np.newaxis` on the location of the dimenstion where you want this new axis.

```
board[np.newaxis,:] -> puts the axis in the first dimension [1,1,16]
board[:,np.newaxis] -> puts the axis in the second dimension [1,1,16]
board[:,:,np.newaxis] -> puts the axis in the third dimension [1,16,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method (it is easy to locate the new axis and does only involves the `None` builtin):

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.array([[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
print(a1[:,:,None].shape)
```

As Mad Physicist mentions, this is strictly equivalent to using `np.newaxis`: `print(np.newaxis)` returns `None`.

Comment: `np.newaxis` is a direct reference to `None`

Comment: I know, but I find remembering `None` easier than `np.newaxis`. Preferences may vary :-)

Comment: I happen to agree with both your preference and your comment. Just wanted to make it explicit for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

try with reshape :

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0]])

print(a.reshape(1,16,1).shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use [**`numpy.expand_dims()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) as in:

```
# input arrray
In [41]: arr
Out[41]: array([[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [42]: arr.shape
Out[42]: (1, 16)

# insert a singleton dimension at the end    
In [44]: arr_3D = np.expand_dims(arr, -1)

# desired shape
In [45]: arr_3D.shape
Out[45]: (1, 16, 1)
```

---

Other ways for *array promotion* are:

```
In [47]: arr[..., None]

In [48]: arr[..., np.newaxis]
```